# free() crashes, but only if more than a certain size of memory is allocated

Tags: c, malloc, free, mpi

I have a strange problem freeing allocated memory in my mpi program:

Here is a code sample that produces the error for me:

```
void *out, *in;
int cnt = 2501; //if cnt<=2500: works perfectly. cnt>2500: crashes at free!

if((out = malloc(cnt * sizeof(double))) == NULL) 
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_ERR_OP);
if((in = malloc(cnt * sizeof(double))) == NULL) 
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_ERR_OP);

//Test data generation
//usage of MPI_Send and MPI_Reduce_local
//doing a lot of memcpy, assigning pointer synonyms to in and out, changing data to in and out

free(in);    //crashes here with "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer" 
free(out);   //and here (if above line is commented out) with "double free or corruption (!prev)"
```

I ran it using valgrind:

```
 mpirun -np 2 valgrind  --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes  ./foo
```

and got the following:

```
==6248== Warning: ignored attempt to set SIGRT32 handler in sigaction();
==6248==          the SIGRT32 signal is used internally by Valgrind
cr_libinit.c:183 cri_init: sigaction() failed: Invalid argument

==6248== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6248==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6248==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 25 bytes allocated
==6248== 
==6248== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6248== 
=====================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 134
```

Any ideas about how to track this error down? Note that it only appears if cnt>2500!

Comment: The valgrind output doesn't look like that of a full run that is representative of your error. Note *"1 allocs, 1 frees, ..."*. Hard to tell what's going on with more information. My wild guess would be that memory pointed to by `in` is being overwritten.

Comment: Looks like an overrun somewhere in the code not shown, as @ShawnChin says. Not necessarily overrun on `in`, maybe (even more likely, I think), overrun of `out`.

Comment: I can't find anything in https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/clresctr/vxrx/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cluster.pe.v5r1.pe400.doc%2Fam106_msl.htm to indcate what the problem could be. Can you please post any lines of code that use the out pointer and the in pointer, it doesn't have to compile but it does need to be in order and include them all. in addition please print the address of in and out at the beginning, and then near the end before trying to free them, print them again, and see if they are different. printf("in %d out %d\n",(int)in,(int)out);

Comment: looking further, it appears as if valgrind can't yank control of free() and malloc() like it wants to. this appears to happen with MPI sometimes, I'm not too familiar with it though. I can't find anything about MPI taking control off malloc() and free() either...?

Comment: Shawn and std''OrgnlDave: You are right, valgrind was not set up correctly. @ugoren: you are right, there was an overrun of out! Would you like to post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re using GNU glibc, you can set the environment variable MALLOC_CHECK_ to 2 before running your program, to enable extra checking on memory-allocation calls—details [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html).

Answer (score 1):

The message you had above,

> Warning: ignored attempt to set SIGRT32 handler in sigaction(); the
>   SIGRT32 signal is used internally by Valgrind cr_libinit.c:XXX
>   cri_init: sigaction() failed: Invalid argument

has to do with the MPI's (mine is mpich-3.1.4-9) use of the BLCR checkpointing libraries (mine is blcr-0.8.5)

When I had no support for BLCR (run "mpiexec -info" and look at the "Checkpointing libraries available" line) Valgrind was working perfectly during my test phase.

When I recompiled my MPI for BLCR support (for Checkpointing experiments) Valgrind got heart-attack. He stopped working totally.

The bug (as the programmers say,) is very bad, because obviously the two programs use the same signalling for their interrupts to your running program, and simply they cannot do so. (In our case the BLCR for MPI got it first and now Valgrind is left walking on the air).

I will try to run two different installations of MPI to the same machine (one with blcr support and one without), and I hope I will alternate happily between Valgrind and Checkpoint.

UPDATE:

Even if Checkpoint itself was working, it was not possible to run any mpiexec parallel executables (programs that they were working before).
Mpiexec command itself, was crashing when I was USING (the compiled in) checkpointing library BLCR.

**SOLUTION:**

I recompiled MPI (mpich-3.1.4-9)  **WITHOUT**  BLCR support (I put BLCR out completely) and I installed the DMTCP checkpointing solution (dmtcp-2.4.4) that not only works transparently, but it is also faster than BLCR (you will find the benchmarks in the bibliography).

**Now everything runs as intended :) and the handling of the checkpointed jobs is done properly too.** In the future I will do more heavy tests of DMTCP (I will use local files that will have heavy/active IO from the parallel program).

PS. I also found out that mpich has put out completely the BLCR from their distribution (July 2016).